# Stored procedure - query tables that might not exists within a dynamic SQL statement

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm new to Big Query and I'm trying to create a stored procedure that will return the result (UNION) of a potential of 7 tables. I have to create a dynamic statement because the table names changes every day with the dates.

As an example, the table name today are going to be:

- MyDataset.MYTABLE_20231125
- MyDataset.MYTABLE_20231124
- MyDataset.MYTABLE_20231123
- MyDataset.MYTABLE_20231122
- MyDataset.MYTABLE_20231121
- MyDataset.MYTABLE_20231120
- MyDataset.MYTABLE_20231119

The dynamic portion works fine as I'm able to create the complete string which I execute at the end with an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. The problem is that within the procedure, I have to check the existence of the table with a :

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
           FROM INFORMATION_TABLE.TABLES 
           WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable_20231125') THEN

    SET dynamic_sql = CONCAT(dynamic_sql, 'SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM MyTable_20231125 UNION ALL'
```

Thus, I'm having this check within a WHILE LOOP and again, my dynamic SQL statement is built perfectly upon the completion.

The problem reside when I'm executing the stored procedure itself.  I'm getting 8 result sets because it returns every single execution of the `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1....)` + the execution of my dynamic query at the end. I only want one result set, the execution of the dynamic query.

Is there any way to achieve this or am I asking too much of Big Query? :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using wildcard tables and _TABLE_SUFFIX to filter for the tables you want.  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables .  This will avoid loops altogether.

Comment: The problem actually is that I cannot query the tables directly, I have to go through the APPEND TVF to queries the tables because basically I need the change_timestamp value which can only be provided by using this function.  It seems that wilcards cannot be used this way using a TVF.  Sorry I forgot to specify this at first